# Migrate an exisiting mobile application from Android Native(Java) and IOS Native(Swift) to React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-play, app-store

I have applictions in both play store(Android) and app store(IOS) up and running which is built using Android Native and Swift. I want to migrate to React Native, as the current app really buggy i'm building the app from scratch using React Native. Now I want to upload the React Native app in both play store and app store under the same project which is being used for Native apps as an update.  I wanna know if there will be a conflicts or problems while puslishing the app under the same project in play store and app store consoles.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no problem while publishing the app. You just have to upgrade its version. Your package name (Android) and bundle identifier (IOS) should be the same as your previous app. For Android, your Keystore should also be the same.